# Data passing from Javascript to MVC controller

Tags: javascript

I need to pass data from javascript to a controller in MVC app. How can this be achieved? I would like to set a ViewModel property and then read that in the controller. My JavaScript:

```
function DoInfo@(i.ToString())() {
         $("#SelectedSession").val($("#sessionid@(i.ToString())").val());
         alert($("#sessionid@(i.ToString())").val());
         $("#PageController").val(70);
         $("#formID").submit();
    }
```

I get the alert with right sessionid but it is null when I read it in the controller as viewModel.SelectedSession. But PageController is righlty set so I assumed I can use the same way to do the SelectedSession.

```
 if (viewModel.PageController == 70) 
        {
            pass = new PassingData();
            pass.personid = TSSessionService.ReadPersonId(viewModel.SelectedSession);
            TempData["pass"] = pass;

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Info");
        }
```

Any clues?

Comment: Is "SelectedSession" part of your form ?

Comment: can u post your html as well?

Comment: SelectedSession is viewmodel property.

Comment: <td class="todo"><input id="Info@(i.ToString())" class="button3" style="cursor: pointer;" value="Info" type="button" onclick="javascript:DoInfo@(i.ToString())();"/></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add SelectedSession to your view as a field (maybe a hidden field if you do not want to show it to whoever is using the application)

On your view, inside the form being submitted, add

```
<%=Html.HiddenFor(Model=>Model.SelectedSession)%>
```

Comment: <input id="SelectedSession" value="@Model.SelectedSession" type="hidden" />